# Sorting uniform random numbers using Matlab Function in Simulink

Tags: simulink

I am a novice learner in Simulink. I have been trying to sort the uniform random numbers in ascending order using the Matlab Function block in Simulink. Somehow it did not work. Here is the code that I wrote in a MATLAB function

```
function y = fcn(u)
%#codegen

y =sort(log(u)/-0.0089);
```

Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: Why didn't it work?  Did you get an error?  If so, what was it.  Are the numbers wrong?  If so, give an example.

Comment: This part of the function looks good. How are you calling `fcn`, in other words, what is `u`? Please make a minimal, complete and verifiable example (http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: It did not give me any error. When I tried to view the result of y in scope, it is still in randomized order not in ascending order. The example is like this.I want to generate uniform random numbers from 0 to 1. So the u here is the uniform random number block from simulink (that is the input). And after that, I used Matlab function block. Here I have to write a matlab code that is function y=fcn(u) %#codegen

y =sort(u); As far as I know, the simulink will automatically assign the uniform random number as u in the Matlab function block.I hope my explanation is clearer than before.

Answer (score 0):

Using exactly your function, the following model does as expected.  What else are you doing?

[image]

Comment: Hi Phil. Thanks for this. How do I want to sort the random number I got from the output using sort function? How do you copy paste this image from the Matlab? Can you teach me how?It is easier if I can show you.

Comment: And also do you know how to accumulate all the random numbers in an array in simulink? Do you know which particular block should I use to keep them in an array?

Comment: The above is a screen shot, not an image exported from MATLAB.

Comment: I have another question, if say we have a matrix with 12 rows, and 2 columns. The first column represents the state, which has values 1 and 2 respectively. The second column represents some random numbers. If I want to find the lowest random number from that matrix, how do I go about it? I did try to use min, but it does not give the expected result.

Comment: If it's another question, then ask it as another question, don't tack it onto this unrelated question.